# Webcam Access for php project

Tags: php, google-chrome, webcam

I am making a project in php and want to use webcam and upload photo directly by clicking on it.

It's showing me

You have denied camera access.

Look for camera icon around your address bar to change your decision.

I enabled it from chrome setting but still it showing same error.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an ssl certificate (`https://`) in order to use webcam. If you test it on localhost you can create self-signed certificate for test purposes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) is some info on how to do that using openssl.